# jQuery click post multiple requests

Tags: jquery

I have simple click that executes post(). This click also triggers  link. So I tried to prevent it and after sending post and hitting ok, the link should execute. Not working after clicking ok.

Code:

```
$( ".prodlink" ).click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var f=$(this).attr('href');                 
                    // product id
                    var product_id = f.match(/product_id=([^&]+)/)[1];  
                    var website_url = '<?php if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];} else { echo 'Unknown';} ?>';
                    var datum = '<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>';                     


                    $.post("<?php echo HTTP_SERVER; ?>/catalog/affiliatecollections/initiate.php",{product_id:product_id,click:1,website_url:website_url, datum: datum},
                        function(event) {       
                                alert("You are leaving this page");                                     
                                //location.reload();
                            }    
                        );                  
                     return true;                               
            })
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7brvk3wL/)

Comment: I think your best bet would be to use a modal window with actual <a target="_blank">OK</a> tag for user to click on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how it works. The link will execute while the post is running.

Instead do this:

```js
$(".prodlink").on("click",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var f = $(this).attr('href');
  // product id
  var product_id = f.match(/product_id=([^&]+)/)[1];
  var website_url = '...';
  var datum = '...';
  $.post("...", {
      product_id: product_id,
      click: 1,
      website_url: website_url,
      datum: datum
    },
    function(event) {
      alert("You are leaving this page");
      location.replace(f); // HERE you execute the link
      // or 
      // window.open(f,"_blank")
    }
  );
});
```

Alternatively have the new page execute the post

**UPDATE**

IF the link looks like this

```
<a href="newpage.html" target="_blank" class="prodlink">click</a>
```

then you simple should be able to do without the preventDefault:

```js
$(".prodlink").on("click",function(e) {
  var f = $(this).attr('href');
  // product id
  var product_id = f.match(/product_id=([^&]+)/)[1];
  var website_url = '...';
  var datum = '...';
  $.post("...", {
      product_id: product_id,
      click: 1,
      website_url: website_url,
      datum: datum
    },
    function() { console.log("succcess") }
  );
});
```

Comment: this works but I need to open it in new tab, is that possible?

Comment: window.open(f,"_blank") isn't working right as the browser blocks it

Comment: that gives me the original problem that it posts multiple times for unknown reason. I will stay with your first suggestion. It's ok if it won't open in new tab, there is a message provided, so it's ok. Thanks

Comment: If there is only Ineke link, use ID instead. If more, set a data-attribute to a value and test it before posting. Without more html I cannot help more. And now really bedtime

Comment: the link have couple of other html tags

Answer (score 1):

why not just use

```
window.location.replace($(".prodlink").attr('href'))
```

Comment: it needs to be target blank too